# Undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass in RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a `Page` resource for which the `create` action in the **pages_controller.rb** file looks as follows:

```
def create
  @page = Page.new(page_params)
    if @page.save
      flash[:notice] = "#{@page.name} was created successfully."
      redirect_to pages_url
    else
      render 'new'    
  end
end

private
  def page_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:name, :content)     
end
```

And the following test in the **pages_controller_spec.rb** file:

```
describe PagesController do
  describe "POST Create'" do
    it "creates a new page" do
      Page.should_receive(:new)
      post :create, page: {name: "Foo", content: "Bar"}
    end
  end
end
```

Which produces the following error: **undefined method 'save' for nil:NilClass**

I'm just starting out with RSpec; so surely I've either made a mistake or I am overlooking something simple. Also, I'm following the "RSpec Book", which goes on to add: `page = mock_model(Page).as_null_object` right before `Page.should...`, but I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
Page.should_receive(:new)
```

you're essentially stubbing it. This is short for:

```
Page.should_receive(:new).and_return(nil)
```

That's why you're getting the error on nil:NilClass. What you could do is either chaining a call to [and_call_original](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method), which would look like this:

```
Page.should_receive(:new).and_call_original
```

or you specifically return a mock, something along the lines of:

```
Page.should_receive(:new).and_return(mock_model(Page))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the page.yml in fixture folder may be because of that it not saving the 
page.In my app i have added the blue
print.rb for structure of  my model.